# How can I iterate over an object and assign all it properties to a list

Tags: python

From

```
a = []

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myinstatt1 = 'one'
        self.myinstatt2 = 'two'
```

to

```
a =['one','two']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enumerate an object's properties in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251692/how-to-enumerate-an-objects-properties-in-python)

Answer (score 9):

Python has a handy builtin called vars that will give the attributes to you as a dict:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> vars(a)
{'myinstatt2': 'two', 'myinstatt1': 'one'}
```

To get just the attribute values, use the appropriate `dict` method:

```
>>> vars(a).values()
['two', 'one']
```

In python 3, this will give you a slightly different thing to a list - but you can just use `list(vars(a).values())` there.

Comment: didn't know about vars, nice!

Answer (score 2):

Try to look into the  `__dict__` attribute.  It will help you:

```
a = A().__dict__.values()
print a
>>> ['one', 'two']
```

Comment: Given that A is the class, shouldn't it be A().__dict__.values()?