# Python 3.6.1: How to dynamically print a docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, printing, docstring

While reading some Python training books, I was tinkering a little bit with objects, like printing docstrings for common objects and attributes.

Consider the list of strings returned by:

```
dir(str)
```

I am trying to iterate over the above in order to dynamically print the docstrings of the attributes stored in the dir list with the following loop:

```
for item in dir(str):
    print(item.__doc__)
```

This returns the dir output for the str object and not for its attribute though, which is not what I'm looking for. How can I dynamically print instead the docstring for all the attributes that populate the list produced by the dir method?

**EDIT**: this is NOT a duplicate of this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251692/how-to-enumerate-an-objects-properties-in-python).
Using the word "enumerate" is very misleading, at least to me, so I would say that question is improperly titled in fact I spent a lot of time looking for a solution and no search query ever returned that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enumerate an object's properties in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251692/how-to-enumerate-an-objects-properties-in-python)

Comment: using the word "enumerate" is very misleading, at least to me, so I would say that question is improperly titled in fact I spent a lot of time looking for a solution and no search query ever returned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getattr(obj, attr)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the named attribute from the object.

```
for item in dir(str):
    print(getattr(str, item).__doc__)
```

Comment: `print(len(vars(str))) --> 68`, `print(len(dir(str)))-->76`, this one is more complete

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `dir`, which just gives you the names of attributes, use `vars` - this gives you a dict of names to the actual method objects.

```
for name, method in vars(str).items():
    print(name, method.__doc__)
```

Comment: thanks this works as well as the reply from khelwood. I find though that there is no need to invoke this dictionary because you get the same results by:

`for item in dir(var):
    print(item, '\n', getattr(str, item).__doc__)`

thanks a lot. this being said, in your opinion, should I still pick the dict way?