# Collections of Models in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, model

Is there the concept of collections of Models in Python 3.

For example, if I have something like

```py
class Game(object):
    id = ''
    status = Status()
    home = Team()
    away = Team()
```

How can I then have a collection of "Game"s ?

Something that I could then append another "Game" to, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `list` for instance, e.g. `[Game()]`, and use `list.append` to append another game.  You can also annotate the name holding such collection as `list[Game]` for it to be checked by a static type checker like mypy.

Comment: Thanks, I had the opening [ in the wrong place.   :-P

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to get all the items from the class "Game"?

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251702/12036707